# Data Mining on data using pandas and series in Python?

Tags: python, database, dataframe, numpy, series

[Data_Image_Part_1]

[image: 1]

[Data_Imagine_Part_2]

[image: 2]

[Column names and index name (forgot to add in image part 1][image: 3]
I am trying to figure out for this data set:

1. How to find the major of the students whose FIDN is 30?

   My idea: `df_test.get_value(30, 'Major')`
    but I do not know if this is correct
2. How can I sort all the students by their last name, then by their tuition amount?

   My idea: `df_test.sort_values( ['LastName', 'tuition'] )` 

    but this does not work and outputs just the column names and index name :(

Answer (score 0):

1. `df_test[df_test["FIDN"] == 30]["Major"]`
   OR:  `df_test.loc[df_test["FIDN"] == 30]["Major"]`
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071908/9169359
2. `df_test.sort_values(by=["LastName", "tuition"], ascending=False)`
   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html